# Use of anonymous inner class in traversing a binary search tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, anonymous-inner-class

Update: how best can I add up the durations without modifying the interface?

I cannot access a method of an instance of an anonymous inner class. I get a compile-time error for the sum.totalTime() call -- "the method totalTime() is undefined for the type Traverser"

I have a Traverser interface.

```
interface Traverser<E> {
    public void visit(E x);
}
```

I'd like to use the interface to add up the duration attributes of a SongEntry object. As a result, I instantiated an anonymous inner class, with a totalTime attribute to be augmented for each visit() call, and a getter for that attribute.

In another class, I have the following code:

```
Traverser<SongEntry> sum = new Traverser<SongEntry>() {
  private int totalTime;

  public void visit(SongEntry song) {
    totalTime += song.getDuration();
  }

  public int totalTime() {
    return totalTime;
  }
};

myPlayList.traverse(sum);

int total = sum.totalTime(); // causes compile-time error "the method totalTime() is undefined for the type Traverser<SongEntry>"
```

myPlayList is a binary search ADT, which runs the visit() method of a passed functor on each element.

Comment: So the question is "How can I use the new methods in an anonymous class from outside the class?"?

Comment: If I'm doing something wrong in my current usage, then yes, that is my question ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `sum` is of type `Traverser`, you can only call on methods declared in the `Traverser` interface.  Your options are:

- Just add the function `public int totalTime();` to the interface
  definition.
- Create a 2nd interface with the desired function declaration that
  extends `Traverser`.
- Create an inner class that is not anonymous and implements
  `Traverser`.

Comment: Is there a way to call the method without changing the interface definition?

Comment: @Rishi No, so I would define an inner class that's not anonymous and implements your Traverser interface.

Comment: I opted for the third option, as a note to future visitors of this page.